# How do I run the Android Emulator in Windows on a Mac OS machine with Parallels installed?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting the following error messages.  So many messages that I am not sure where to start.  Are there some steps I need to take.  The emulator(s) will not start when I try it with the Android device manager.

[image]

Comment: Have followed all the steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=macos) about emulator in Visual-Studio for mac? You can also [Viewing Device Manager logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=macos).